# Android Material Slider from Max to Min

Tags: android, material-components-android

Thats a little simple question, but unfortunately i did not find any info.

I need to set slider to max, so user slide to the left to min value.

Thats default behavior:

[image: Thats default behavior]

Thats how I want:

[image: Thats how I want]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the property of **layoutDirection**

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="100"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"/>
```

Or if you want to set maximum value as default:

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="100"
        android:value="100"/>
```